# How to move folders with multiple anomalies?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a line of code that has 2 anomalies. However the code does not run. I have tried putting a tilde sign in front of my second anomaly to delate it but it still not function. any advice?

```
Sub PAUL_COMPLETE()

Dim fso As Object

Dim src_path As String
Dim dest_path As String

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

src_path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\USERS\*\COMPLETED\*"
dest_path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\READY TO BILL\DEPARTMENT REVIEW\"

On Error Resume Next

fso.MoveFolder src_path, dest_path

On Error Resume Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What are the two anomalies? Why doesn't the code run? What goes wrong? What does "delate" mean? You should read [ask].

Comment: I have the asterisk to represent the anomaly. In m Users folder the are 10 users that have completed subfolders.  I can move the subfolders by replacing the first asterist with their name. However i do not ant to write a new line of code every time i create a new user. Delate was suppose to be Elate.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sub folders

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PAUL_COMPLETE()

    Dim fso As Object, fldUser As Object
    Dim root_path As String, src_path As String, dest_path As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    root_path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\USERS\"
    dest_path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\READY TO BILL\DEPARTMENT REVIEW\"
    
    For Each fldUser In fso.GetFolder(root_path).SubFolders
        src_path = fldUser.Path & "\COMPLETED\*"
        On Error Resume Next
        fso.MoveFolder src_path, dest_path
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That is what i was missing. Thank you so much that worked great.